# Intermittently update database using java program every 5 minutes on Linux machine

Tags: java, linux, webserver

I apologize in advance for this complicated post.
I need to find a way to automatically update a database with information from calls to a web service every 5 minutes. I plan to write a Java program that will pull data from a web service on the cloud and put it in the database. I will need this program to pull from the cloud every 5 minutes or so, so that we get data sequentially through time. What would be a good way to implement this? This would be done on a server computer running Linux.

I'm thinking of two possibilities:
1.
I could write a Java Program in an endless loop that runs 24 hours a day on the server, and sleeps its thread for 5 minutes at a time. If so, how would I make sure that the server computer keeps the program running? And that it would start running again if the server rebooted? I would need some way to automate that. Any ideas?
or
2.
I could write a non-looping program and somehow get the operating system or other software to run the program every 5 minutes. Is there some way to make Linux or server software to do this? Any ideas?

If anybody can point me in the right direction it would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Take a look at [Quartz Scheduler](http://quartz-scheduler.org/)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You mention two different "technologies" that have different approach to your disposal, one is Java, the second is linux.

On linux you have

1. CRON - this is a 'linux' way to execute scheduled tasks (scripts) so you can run your java program/whatever you want each 5 minutes. Defined correctly you shouldn't be bothered by the service reboot, cron will run automatically upon the service reboot and will handle your java program. You might want to use anacron instead, but you should talk to your system administator for the details here.
2. If you don't want to run scheduled job in linux and wan't to manage scheduling in Java, you indeed can write a program that will run in the endless loop by means of that the process will run forever, but in this case I would suggest you to use java.util.Timer instead of sleeps, or if you don't mind to use thirdparties - than go for Quartz, its a full fledged Java scheduler. But then in order to make this program running upon reboot you should define it as a service in linux. Basically, you put some script (defined properly) in a predefined folder, register the service and linux upon reboot will call this script, so that you'll be able to run if you want.

   service myscheduledtask start/stop/status

The technical details slightly change depending on Linux distribution but the infrastructure for running scheduled task exists in any distribution for sure
For example on Redhat you should look at `chkconfig` command as an entry point.

Now what approach is better? There is no silver-bullet solution here. I would probably go with cron based approach, because its easier. But being myself a java programmer I realize that java will provide a crossplatform solution (if one day you'll move to another operating system, than you'll have to define the scheduling mechanism again).
On the other hand its always better to have less processes, so an always-running process is a drawback here :) So, the choice is yours

Hope this helps

Answer (score 1):

Linux has a program cron which can start your java program every 5 minutes if you wish.

Answer (score 1):

You could probably set a cron job that calls a java program you coded to retrieve the data from your web service at your specified intervals(5 minutes in your sample).

Check out the wiki article for info.

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cron

Answer (score 1):

I would create a program that do just the task I need, and then schedule it with, for example, cron.

Answer (score 1):

> 1) I could write a Java Program in an endless loop that runs 24 hours a day on the server, and sleeps its thread for 5 minutes at a time. If so, how would I make sure that the server computer keeps the program running?

Run it as a daemon process that gets started automatically when the server reboots.

> And that it would start running again if the server rebooted?

Read up on "init" for your particular flavour of Linux.  (I can't be more specific, because there are at least 3 kinds of "init" system in common use on different Linux distros.)

> 2) I could write a non-looping program and somehow get the operating system or other software to run the program every 5 minutes. Is there some way to make Linux or server software to do this?

Read up on ["cron"](http://linux.die.net/man/8/cron) and ["crontab"](http://linux.die.net/man/1/crontab).